# Using wicked_pdf with rtl languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, right-to-left, wicked-pdf

I have added wicked_pdf plugin in my rails applications to generate pdf. It works fine in normal case. But when it is used for rtl (right to left) languages it get zoomed (or may be auto resizing to fit the page is not working in rtl). How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to the `wkhtmltopdf` application that pdf get zoomed. Wicked pdf hav nothing to do with it. I this the developers of `wkhtmltopdf` has to check it fix this bug.

Comment: i would recommend posting a link to the issue here

Comment: Its not a public app. So I cant post its link here sorry sir. If you are the developer of wkhtmltopdf I can give you more details in private.